Pyspark Deduplication Approach
I'm trying to dedupe some large skewed data, of uids, timestamps, and another set of session_ids. The second set of IDs somewhat low cardinality. I'm trying to dedupe the Spark DF across these 3 columns. There some high level skewness as these are observation data, and on many days we have alot more observations while others have much less, which seems to impact performance. I ask generally what is the best way to approach this?
I've tried drop_duplicates(< 3 columns here>), I've tried row_number (currently what I'm still using), I've tried an agg group by, but I'm not sure that will work as this DF has 3 additional columns that I would like to retain.
Appreciate any advice!

And how to select from those additional columns if there are duplicates based on the other 3 keys? Also could you please provide an example input and output?

Do a broadcast join with smaller set of ids dataframe broadcasted.
